# WPF set a value of a string from XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I was wondering if it is possible to set a value to a string every time someone selects a new date from the datepicker in my XAML. i have a public String called test12. thanks a lot everyone for your help in advance

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="testprojectgrid">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Start}" />
              </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                     <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding}" />
         </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: why dont  you store the SelectedDate in DateTime property and use StringFormat to display it in any format you want?

Comment: i am just trying to learn how to set value to a string.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but if find it strange that Text is bound to "Start" but SelectedDate is bound to the DataContext itself.. Your DataContext have to be a DateTime, but DateTime doesn't have any Start property..

Answer (score 0):

You can store the SelectedDate in DateTime property and use StringFormat to display it in any format you want.

Else you can use IValueConverter to convert the DateTime to string and string back to DateTime

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string date = value as string;
            return DateTime.Parse(date);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value.ToString();
        }
    }

<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Start, RelativeSource={xxxxxx}, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a handler for the `DatePicker.SelectedDateChanged` event:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding}" 
    SelectedDateChanged="DatePicker_SelectionChanged" />

private void DatePicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker)sender;
    test12 = datePicker.SelectedDate.ToString();
}
```

You can find out more from the [DatePicker.SelectedDateChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.selecteddatechanged.aspx) page at MSDN.